# VMWare Workstation's strange bootloader behaviour (failing to print a character)

Tags: bootloader, bios, vmware-workstation

```
.code16
.text
.org 0x0 

.global _start

_start:
  jmp _testing
  nop

_testing:
  mov $0x0E, %ah 
  mov the_byte, %al       #the line in question
  int $0x10

  jmp .

the_byte: .byte 0x41

.fill (510-(.-_start)), 1, 0
.word 0xAA55
```

This simple 'bootloader', as it were, is supposed to print out `A` to the screen, but it fails to do so when I'm using [VMWare Workstation 16](https://www.vmware.com/products/workstation-pro/workstation-pro-evaluation.html) (unlike [Bochs](https://bochs.sourceforge.io/), which happily shows `A` on its screen). If I change *the line in question* to

```
mov $0x41, %al
```

I can see `A` on VMWare Workstation as well.
Have you by any chance got any idea what can be causing such strange behaviour?

PS. It is indeed loaded into 0x7C00 with a separate linker file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, `mov the_byte, %al` is assembled into something akin to `mov %ds:0x7C0C, %al`, hence DS had to be zeroed out (along with other segment pointers):

```
cli
mov  %cs, %ax # CS is set to 0x0
mov  %ax, %es # ES = CS = 0x0           
mov  %ax, %ds # DS = CS = 0x0            
mov  %ax, %ss # SS = CS = 0x0
sti
```